# Migrating Devstack to subdomain cannot login to Horizon dashboard

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone, openstack-horizon

I changed the Apache2 virtual host to put horizon on a subdomain so I can access it easier from abroad. I added the domain and subdomain to the local_settings.py for horizon and restarted horizon.

I have added the subdomain and domain to the keystone.conf.

I still cannot login to the horizon admin panel.

What do I need to do in order to be able to login?

The error I am getting is:

```
    2016-09-11 03:24:34.075089 DEBUG:keystoneauth.identity.v3.base:Making authentication request to http://192.168.1.26/identity/v3/auth/tokens
    2016-09-11 03:24:34.084492 DEBUG:keystoneauth.session:Request returned failure status: 500
    2016-09-11 03:24:34.084970 Login failed for user "lanerjo".
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your keystone URL is incorrect:

```
keystoneauth.identity.v3.base:Making authentication request to http://192.168.1.26/identity/v3/auth/tokens
```

keystone operates on an admin (35357) and public port so your url should be

```
http://192.168.1.26:5000/identity/v3/auth/tokens
```